# Scapy - WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast? When I try send a packet to a IP outside LAN

Tags: python, tcp, network-programming, scapy

I am using Scapy, I try to send TCP/IP packet to outside LAN IP, like facebook.com

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.inet import TCP, IP


def send_ip_tcp(IP_dst, src_port, dst_port, data):
    packet = IP(dst=IP_dst) / TCP(flags='S', sport=src_port, dport=dst_port) / data
    send(packet)
    print("packet send successfully")


byteArr = 'This data send from Python'.encode('utf-8')
ip_dst = '157.240.218.35'  # facebook.com

send_ip_tcp(IP_dst=ip_dst, src_port=52320, dst_port=4001, data=byteArr)
```

And I saw:

```
WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.
.
Sent 1 packets.
packet send successfully
```

I know something about firewall, maybe it block my packet, even so WireShark cannot capture anything with ip.dst == 157.240.218.35

My IP I want to send is the IP that my computer id connected with, I've capture in WireShark, how can I send a packet for injection. The title of question may be duplicated, but the content is different